# NameError: class name is not defined, despite being imported

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I wrote a project with Spyder which contains several module files, such as tester.py and scheduler.py. I created the following classes in tester.py:

```
class Tester(object):
    def run(self):
        pass
```

When I imported Tester class to the scheduler.py, I got a name error(I used Anaconda Prompt to access the project folder and run `python scheduler.py`):

```
from tester import Tester
class Scheduler():
    def schedule_tester(self):
        getter = Tester()
        while True:
            getter.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = Scheduler()
    scheduler.schedule_tester()

Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'Tester' is not defined
```

Can someone help me figure out, many thanks!

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: in which file `class Tester` has been created?

Comment: The error message was quite short. I have written all of them.class Tester was in tester.py.

Answer (score 1):

Your scheduler class instantiates getter as an instance of the Tester class.
Then you try to use the run method on the imported Tester class.
This is impossible since it is a normal method and not a classmethod.
I think you want to call getter.run() instead of Tester.run() in your while loop.
So your Scheduler would look like this:

```
class Scheduler():
    def schedule_tester(self):
        getter = Tester()
        while True:
            getter.run() # not Tester.run()
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post. The original one was actually ```getter.run()```. But still got an error message.

Comment: This would not explain the `NameError`